# Parsing CSV data in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this,

```
date, hid, hname, hscore, aid, aname, ascore
2016-01-01, 1, Nickleback,100, 2, Blink 182, 99
2016-02-02, 3, Travis, 10, 4, Coldplay, 120
2016-03-03, 1, Nickleback, 2, 4, Coldplay, 1000
```

What I am wanting to do is parse each unique name into it's own object/array so I would be left with something like this,

```
{
    [
        "name" => "Nickleback",
        "score" => 102 //aggregate of all scores for this band
    ],
    [
       "name" => "Blink 182",
       "score" => 99
    ],
    [
       "name" => "Travis",
       "score" => 10
    ],
    [
      "name" => "Coldplay",
      "score" => 1120
    ]
}
```

I can get an array of unique names out like this,

```
$fd = fopen("../data/results.csv", "r");
while(($row = fgetcsv($fd, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $uniques[$row[2]] = true;
}

var_dump(array_keys($uniques));
```

But how I do then assign further data to each array? Like the scores and dates?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array in the loop:

```
$fd = fopen("../data/results.csv", "r");
while(($row = fgetcsv($fd, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $uniques[$row[2]] = [
       "name" => ""
       "score" => ""
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (but you'll need to check if $row[2] and $row[4] are ok):

```
$rows = array();
$fd = fopen("../data/results.csv", "r");
while(($row = fgetcsv($fd, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $rowId = $row[1];
    if (isset($rows[$rowId])) {
       $rows[$rowId]['score'] += $row[4];
    } else {
       $rows[$rowId] = array('name' => $row[2], 'score' => $row[4]);
    }
 }

 var_dump(array_keys($uniques));
```